# Expressão similar para "Mamão com açúcar" em Português Europeu

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

A expressão "mamão com açúcar" existem em Portugal? Caso não, existe alguma expressão similar que possa ser utilizada?

Em português brasileiro, "mamão com açúcar" representa algo muito fácil, algo como "piece of cake" em inglês

Comment: Exatamente, "a piece of cake" é uma boa tradução para "mamão com açúcar".  Acho que um gráfico no tempo mostraria uma curva em declive para o uso de ambas.

Comment: @Centaurus isso eu sei, minha duvida é se existe essa expressão em Português europeu, estou fazendo uma adaptação de um texto e surgiu essa duvida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moro em Lisboa há mais de 1 ano. E vejo em alguns programas de TV a expressão:

> **ser pêra doce** • [Informal]  Ser fácil; não constituir dificuldade ou
>   obstáculo (ex.: desenganem-se os que acham que o curso é pêra doce;
>   ganhar as eleições não será pêra doce).

Fonte: [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pera)

Answer (score 7):

Uma expressão similar seria "É canja".

Comment: Esta é também usada no Brasil, me recordo de 4: É canja; É baba; É mamão com açúcar; e É Mumu. Esta última Mumu era ou é a marca de um doce de leite no sul do Brasil - A expressão predomina ou é restrita ao sul ou ao estado do RS.

Answer (score 1):

Expressões como "[ser] pêra doce", "canja", "fácil como tirar um doce a uma criança" (que também tem equivalência em inglês).

Se quer dizer que algo é fácil de se fazer, é comum dizer-se que se faz "com uma perna às costas" ou que "fazia isso a dormir".

Se quer dizer que algo é fácil de compreender, evidente, pode antes dizer que isso "é claro como água", "salta à vista", ou que "é de caras".